# How to give remove all options in ExtJS tagfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, tags

I am using extJS `tagfield`. Where I am selecting multiple data from dropdown. I want to give one x icon inside fiedld and on click of cross icon how to remove all the selected values from tagfield.

Can any one suggest me how to achive that.

Comment: Which version of extjs? and for that you can use extjs ItemSelector. thats a cool option

Comment: I am using ExtJS 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example with a button that removes the selected values from a tagfield:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1oku

I'm not sure how you would do this with an x inside the tagfield instead of a button. Perhaps as simple as adding a span inside the tag list wrapper and wiring it to do the same as the button in the fiddle example.

Comment: Clear method I can use for clearing. Let me try a close icon work because my tagfield is widget column. Thanks for help.